# Failed to proxy to maven repo via Nexus

Tags: maven-2, proxy, repository, nexus

I am working with Nexus free addition (1.3.6) and I am trying to add a proxy repository as described in the Nexus book - Google Caja: http://google-caja.googlecode.com/svn/maven.

After adding a new proxy repository and configure the remote location, I tried to re-index the repository but could not see the related artifacts.

was anyone able to proxy a remote repository via Nexus and see its artifacts?

Ronen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, according to the Nexus documentation about [Remote Index Downloads](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/install-sect-repoman-post-install.html#d0e2378):

> Nexus ships with three important proxy
>   repositories for the Central Maven
>   Repository, Apache Snapshot
>   Repository, and the Codehaus Snapshot
>   Repository. Each of these repositories
>   contains thousands (or tens of
>   thousands) of artifacts and it would
>   be impractical to download the entire
>   contents of each. To that end, most
>   repositories maintain a Lucene index
>   which catalogs the entire contents and
>   provides for fast and efficient
>   searching. Nexus uses these remote
>   indexes to search for artifacts, but
>   we've disabled the index download as a
>   default setting. To download remote
>   indexes,
>
> 1. Click on Repositories under the Administration menu and change
>      Download Remote Indexes to true for
>      the three proxy repositories. You'll
>      need to load the dialog shown in
>      Figure 5.9, “Repository Configuration
>      Screen for a Proxy Repository” for
>      each of the three repositories.
> 2. Right-click on each proxy repository and select Re-index. This
>      will trigger Nexus to download the
>      remote index files.
>
> It might take Nexus a few minutes to
>   download the entire index, but once
>   you have it, you'll be able to search
>   the entire contents of the Maven
>   repository.
>
> Once you've enabled remote index
>   downloads, you still won't be able to
>   browse the complete contents of a
>   remote repository. Downloading the
>   remote index allows you to search for
>   artifacts in a repository, but until
>   you download those artifacts from the
>   remote repository they will not show
>   in the repository tree when you are
>   browsing a repository. When browsing a
>   repository, you will only be shown
>   artifacts which have been downloaded
>   from the remote repository.

So, to me, the proxyed remote repository has to provide a Nexus Index (which does not seem to be the case of the repository for Google Caja) to allow **searching** and searching is different from **browsing** (i.e. you'll still have to download artifacts to see them when browsing the repository). That being said, not providing an index doesn't mean the caja repository isn't proxied.

Comment: You've got it. It's unlikely that a repo that appears to be in svn is providing an index. This only affects searching and browsing the content prior to downloading it. Once the artifacts are proxied, they will be browsable and searchable. Just point your build at the repo and it will fetch what you need.